# Find probability given MGF

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm given that the random variable X has MGF 
$M(t)=e^{8t + 8t^2}$ and I need to find the probability $P(1 < X < 5)$. 
I know that we have to recognize the MGF as a familiar one and thereby identify the distribution. I can't seem to recognize this one though. I've tried simplifying it to $e^{8(t + t^2)}$ or $e^{8t(1 + t)}$ but none of those seem to help me.

Comment: Try $\mathcal{N}(m=8, \sigma^2=16)$

Comment: @Mesmerizedstudent I can find those with the first and second derivative at 0 but from then what?

Comment: MGF corresponds to exactly one random variable or in the other words MGF is unique for every r.v. So we find r.v. that has exactly that MGF, what we can derive from that?

Comment: I found that this is how one calculates the normal distribution given mean and variance. Is this how I should proceed? $$P(1-8 < X - \mu < 5 - 8) = P\left(\frac{1-8}{16} < \frac{X - \mu}{16} < \frac{5 - 8}{16}\right)$$

Comment: You are almost precise, just $\sqrt{16}$ instead of $16$. And then you will have standard normal distribution.

Comment: @Mesmerizedstudent thank you :)

Comment: @ThatGuy : "Mesmerized student" wasn't just telling you the expected value and variance, but rather was saying that it's a _normal_ distribution. That's why this should look like something familiar.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- MGF is unique and
- The normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \rho^2)$ has MGF $e^{\mu t + \frac{1}{2}\rho^2t^2}$.